# How can I install SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to install SQL Server 2005 Developer SP3 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

If so, is there anything special that needs to be done to get it to install properly?

Answer (score 3):

It's fully supported, as stated [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/supported-applications.aspx):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 and SQL Server 2008 Service
>   Pack 1 and later versions are supported. SQL Server 2005 Express
>   Edition Service Pack 2 and SQL Server 2008 Express Runtime RTM are
>   also supported.

Just be sure to install the x64 version, as Windows Server 2008 R2 exists only as a x64 system.

Comment: Not that you would want to since there is a 64-bit version, but SQL 2005 32-bit will run on an x64 system.

Comment: That's why I said it... you *can* install the x86 version by mistake :-)